# How to know if an image dataset is learnable/trainable?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics, computer-vision, dataset

I did some research, most of the reponses only answered the question "How is the images get learned", and the answer is through learning hidden features. But I wonder how to determine if a set of images can be learned by a machine learning model, such as a DNN. I understand that the convolutional layers for the current DNN can learn the images and try to extract only useful feature, but is there any study showing a metrics or evaluation of the dataset itself? So that we can say after satisfying some condition, one dataset is learnable.

I tried to search for some papers aiming at this, but I did not find any useful answers for this question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.